# MySQL foreign key constraints : on updating one table, fill another table with some data from the first table

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, knex.js

I have two tables, users table and login table.
Say:

```
Create table users(
 id int not null,
 name varchar not null,
 email varchar not null,
 password varchar not null,
 entries int default 0,
 primary key(id));

Create table login(
 id int not null,
 email varchar not null,
 password varchar not null,
 user_id int not null,
 Primary key(id)),
 Foreign key (user_id) references users(id));
```

What constraints can I add or how can i work my way around such that whenever i add a user in the users table, the **email** and **password** columns are added into the login table too **(just like to say i create a minimized version of the users table which only contains login credentials of users)**. And whenever i delete a user from the users table, he should be removed from the login table.

I hope i have been descriptive enough

Comment: What is the reason to have 2 tables? Does one user may have more than one login?

Comment: No @Akina, the users table may get messy with time(lots of columns), so I just wanted to create a separate table that only contains the login credentials of every user created. Might not be the best of designs but I'm a beginner to database management so it was just a thought that crossed my mind and I was tempted to try.

Comment: If so then store credentials data in `login` table and "a lot of columns", including the reference to logins table, in users table. You'll avoid data duplication.

Answer (score 1):

You can define [constraint with cascade delete](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html). To implement the update of dependent tables you need [triggers](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/trigger-syntax.html). It is possible to define AFTER INSERT trigger where you can update any dependent tables.

At the same time, I would reconsider having redundant fields in the dependent table when you always can obtain it by joining with the main table.